# Deactivate Through Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Are aware of any solution that let me deactivate my facebook account  through an API. Facebook Graph , core libraries anything !! 
I'm working on a mobile app and i want to give the user the ability to deactivate his account from the app IF HE ALREADY AUTHORIZED USING FACEBOOK .
i thought it might be impossible due to a big security issue but i just want to know if any solution existed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the only way for a user to deactivate their account is via Facebook's own UI or apps - there is no API for that functionality